# React.createElement: type is invalid although import/export shouldn't be wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I recently got started with react native. I'm currently trying to learn some react-native navigation. I've got two main classes which I created, following a tutorial. But I always get the same Error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

> Check your code at App.js:10.
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

My homeStack.js looks like this:

```
import {createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";

//import all screens here
import HomeScreen from "./Screens/homescreen";
import CreatePortfolio from "./Screens/createPortfolio";
import ContactUs from "./Screens/ContactUs";
import Portfolio from "./Screens/Portfolio";

const screens = {

    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    },

    CreatePortfolio: {
        screen: CreatePortfolio
    },

    ContactUs: {
        screen: ContactUs
    },

    Portfolio: {
        screen: Portfolio
    },
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);
export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

The App.js class looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Navigator from "./homeStack";

//Root function for navigation etc

export default function App () {
  return(
    <Navigator/>
  );
}
```

The screen classes all look pretty much the same:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, } from 'react-native';
import {GlobalStyles} from "../styles";

export default function homescreen() {
    return(
        <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
            <Text style={GlobalStyles.titleText}>Homescreen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I researched the error but the import/export statements seem fine to me. I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: Please add code for the other components that you have imported

Comment: @DipanSharma I just did. The screen functions only differ in the name and the text

Comment: can you show the global styles css file ?

Comment: if possible share code on expo

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error I'd guess that one of your screens is wrong. Try and figure out which one by creating an MVP that works, and then adding them back in one by one.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: () => <View>It Works!</View>
  }
});
export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

Yes, this is not really an answer and more of a comment.